# Aligning text and other elements vertically works in header, but not in footer

Tags: html, css

I want to create a simple header/content/footer layout as was asked hundreds of times already, and I found one that I really like. I have create [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5Lhsqdt/2/) that showcases the approach. Everything works fine except for the `<footer>` tag.

Basically, I have tried to use a `footerElement` definition analogous to

```
header.headerElement:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
}
```

to accomplish vertically aligned text elements and other stuff inside the `<footer>`, but it doesn't work. As I don't understand what the `:before` trick really does with the `headerElement` class, I think the problem lies in me just copying it and expecting it to work. But I can't find out on my own how to do the same in the footer. What do I have to change/add to get my stuff vertically aligned in the footer as well? It would suffice to accomplish this for text, as I don't think anything else (images) will be used there anyway.

Also, I noticed `color: red` does nothing if put inside the above `header.headerElement:before` block. Is this related to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5Lhsqdt/4/)

Add `line-height: 30px;` to your footer CSS, vertical alignment of children is relative to the line-height of the parent.

As you have `vertical-align:middle` set on the children (`:before`), they need to establish the parameters for their alignment, established using [**line height**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height). As such, setting it to the same as the height of the parent will vertically align them as intendedd.

Comment: Ahhh, I finally understand how `line-height` works now. I remember having had a problem some months ago with that one in combination with another vertical align problem...

Comment: Note that you can also use positioning to do this in a multi-line environment where line-height may not be appropriate. On a positioned child, set `top:50%;transform:translateY(-50%);` : demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f5Lhsqdt/5/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the demo, I'm sorry. Where is anything multi-lined? Btw, I just noticed a misbehaviour in my original code: The `<p>Test</p>` paragraph is not shown. But I guess it's "behind" the header and adding `padding-top: 50px` (and perhaps `padding-bottom` for the bottom) fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `line-height` for footer like this along with your code: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f5Lhsqdt/3/)**

```
footer {      
    line-height:30px; /* added */        
}
```